# Custom Observable Collection with AddRange & NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have implemented an ObservableCollection to support bulk addition like below and bind to a WPF UI  -

```
public void  AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (list == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
                }

                _suspendCollectionChangeNotification = true;
                var newItems = new List<T>();

                foreach (T item in list)
                {
                    if (!Contains(item))
                    {
                        Add(item);
                        newItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                _suspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;

                var arg = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newItems);
                OnCollectionChanged(arg);  //NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset works!!!
            }
        }
    }

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

            protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                NotifyCollectionChanged(e);
            }

            internal void NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (IsCollectionChangeSuspended)
                {
                    return;
                }

                NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = CollectionChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    if (Application.Current != null && !Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind,handler, this, e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler(this, e);
                    }
                }
            }

    private bool IsCollectionChangeSuspended
    {
        get { return _suspendCollectionChangeNotification; }
    }
```

I get this error - **{"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."}**

But, if I change the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` to `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` and do not pass any changed list, then it binds correctly to the UI. But, I want to use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` such that I can observe on the changes.

Can anyone please correct me ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the internal `IList<T>` to add the items it wont notify all the events like using `Add` method,

The `Add` method works like this:

1. CheckReentrancy
2. InsertItem
3. OnPropertyChanged("Count");
4. OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
5. OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);

So if you skip the Add method and add the items directly to the underlying collection you may get this to wok.

Example: (untested)

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> rangeItems)
{
    foreach (var item in rangeItems)
    {
         Items.Add(item);
    }

            base.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            base.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            var arg = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, rangeItems);
            OnCollectionChanged(arg);
}
```